# How to share on Facebook through Javascript with url parameters

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, parameters, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code to share on FB:

```
function shareOnFacebook(blockKey) {
  FB.ui({
    method: "share",
    href: "http://moranplant.org",
  }, function(response){});
};
```

How do I add the blockKey to the link so that the link looks like this:
http://moranplant.org/?blockid=123
where blockKey == 123?

I tried this:

```
href: "http://moranplant.org/?blockid=" + blockKey,
```

But it gives a really weird result for a link:
"http://moranplant.org/?blockid=%27+++blockKey"

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I realized I just need to create the link in a var, and set href to the var.